# Node HTTP request for Restful api's that return JSONP

Tags: http, node.js, jsonp

I am attempting to make server side calls to restful API's using node.js. Returns with JSONP (JSON container inside a JS function) are returning errors that seems to be at the heart of the node http.get(options, callback) API. Can node or any module return the JSON object from a JSONP return?

Example JSONP request:
http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/29/turning-two-founderscard-pulls-back-the-curtain-on-its-membership-community-for-entrepreneurs/

Comment: Can you gist the code? I've noticed there's no callback reference to in the url. Usually this looks like &callback=foo or &jsonp=bar. It looks like LinkedIn responds to callback. You can then use url.parse to find that parameter and act accordingly.

Comment: request = require('request');
request({uri: 'http://graph.facebook.com/?ids=http://appsumo.com'}, function(err, responser, body){ myObject = eval('(' + body + ')');
};

Comment: The callback parameter (&callback=functionName)with linkedin lets me change the wrapper function to any name I wish (but not remove it all together).  If I could get a valid response (JSON or JSONP) from and module or API HTTP request with JS under Node. I would be a happy man.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Execute the callback with [vm](http://nodejs.org/api/vm.html)

```
JavaScript code can be compiled and run immediately or compiled, saved, and run later
```

A previous answer suggests striping the callback function.  Unfortunately, this is not compatible with many jsonp responses since the contents of the function are usually objects and not pure JSON.  The JSON.parse() function will die for something like the following:

```
callback({key:"value"});
```

While the above is a valid object, it is not valid JSON.

The following will execute the callback and return the object:

```
jsonpSandbox = vm.createContext({callback: function(r){return r;}});
myObject = vm.runInContext(jsonpData,jsonpSandbox);
```

When creating the context change `callback` to the name of the callback function that is returned in the jsonp response.

Answer (score 8):

I'd write a wrapper function that checks for JSON and strips the function off the returned string just to avoid running eval.  Then JSON.parse on the string (now minus the function since we removed it) to return json.

```
var request = require('request');
var getJsonFromJsonP = function (url, callback) {
request(url, function (error, response, body) {
  if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
    var jsonpData = body;
    var json;
    //if you don't know for sure that you are getting jsonp, then i'd do something like this
    try
    {
       json = JSON.parse(jsonpData);
    }
    catch(e)
    {
        var startPos = jsonpData.indexOf('({');
        var endPos = jsonpData.indexOf('})');
        var jsonString = jsonpData.substring(startPos+1, endPos+1);
        json = JSON.parse(jsonString);
    }
    callback(null, json);
  } else {
    callback(error);
  }
})
}
```

Then use it like so:

```
getJsonFromJsonP('http://www.linkedin.com/countserv/count/share?url=http://techcrunch.com/2012/01/29/turning-two-founderscard-pulls-back-the-curtain-on-its-membership-community-for-entrepreneurs/', function (err, data) {
    console.log('data count', data.count);
});
```

Comment: This should be published as a NPM module!