# Struggling to translate jQuery JSONP query to a Node.JS query using http.request

Tags: jquery, ajax, node.js, jsonp

Long-time(well, 3 months) reader, first-time poster. I have a client-side jquery AJAX request of some JSONP data which I am trying to switch into a http.request, so I can use it server-side on a Node.js server.

The jQuery works easily enough: JSfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/gk0uttdu/ , code here:

```
  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: 'http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/Api.aspx?Command={"Output":"JSONP","Commands":[{"Name":"Basket","Params":{"BrandStores":["780"],"ProductPrices":{"920":["ASDA","Ocado","Sainsburys","Tesco","Waitrose"],"016555":["ASDA","Sainsburys","Tesco","Waitrose"]},"TrolleyItems":["920","52200","1017"],"TrolleyLinks":["780"]}}]}&banner=34',
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    success: function(json) {
        alert(JSON.stringify(json)); 
    }
});
```

However, when I try to rewrite this request using Node's http module as below, it fails with a 403. I suspect it is because I am not setting dataType:JSONP anywhere.

```
var ajaxUrl = 'http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/Api.aspx?Command={"Output":"JSONP","Commands":[{"Name":"Basket","Params":{"BrandStores":["780"],"ProductPrices":{"920":["ASDA","Ocado","Sainsburys","Tesco","Waitrose"],"016555":["ASDA","Sainsburys","Tesco","Waitrose"]},"TrolleyItems":["920","52200","1017"],"TrolleyLinks":["780"]}}]}&banner=34';

var req = http.request(ajaxUrl, function(res) {
  console.log('STATUS: ' + res.statusCode);
  console.log('HEADERS: ' + JSON.stringify(res.headers));
  res.setEncoding('JSONP');
  res.on('data', function (chunk) {
    console.log('BODY: ' + chunk);
  });
});

req.on('error', function(e) {
  console.log('problem with request: ' + e.message);
});

// write data to request body
console.log('data\n');
console.log('data\n');
req.end();
```

Looked through the http documentation and cannot find how to set it. Also tried the request module for Node with Matt's suggested answer, failed to get that to work either. [Node HTTP request for Restful api's that return JSONP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060270/node-http-request-for-restful-apis-that-return-jsonp)

What is the proper way to do this? Feel like I have been banging head against the wall for a few days, any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: update: used DevTools to inspect the full path of the request coming out of jQuery in the working jsfiddle example.

but when i use that URL for an http.get or request in Node.JS, it comes back 403. why would it work in jsfiddle and then fail within Node?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Needed to fake a user-agent. Did so using the 'request' module in Node. This works

```
request({
    headers: {
      'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (X11; CrOS x86_64 6310.61.0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.94 Safari/537.36',
    },
    uri: 'http://www.mysupermarket.co.uk/Api.aspx?Command={"Output":"JSONP","Commands":[{"Name":"Basket","Params":{"BrandStores":["780"],"ProductPrices":{"920":["ASDA","Ocado","Sainsburys","Tesco","Waitrose"],"016555":["ASDA","Sainsburys","Tesco","Waitrose"]},"TrolleyItems":["920","52200","1017"],"TrolleyLinks":["780"]}}]}&callback=jQuery17102980830231681466_1418310018496&_=1418220018508',
    method: 'GET'
  }, function (err, res, body) {
    if (err) console.log(err)
    else console.log('body', body);

  });
```