# Angular with hapi js server jsonp

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, jsonp, hapi.js

I have an endpoint defined at `/api/profile` which accepts post parameters.

```
var http = require('http');
var serverConfig = require('../server.config.js');
var request = require('request');


module.exports = function(server){
  server.route({
      method: 'POST',
      path: '/api/profile',
      handler: getProfileData
  });


    function getProfileData(request, reply){
        var battleTag = request.payload.battleTag;
        getProfileDataHttp(battleTag, function(err, data){
            if(err){
                reply(new Error(err));
            }
            reply(data);
        });
    }

    function getProfileDataHttp(battleTag, callback){
        var key = serverConfig.battleNet.apiKey;
        var tag =  encodeURIComponent(battleTag);
        var url = 'https://eu.api.battle.net/d3/profile/'+ tag + '/?locale=en_GB&callback=JSON_CALLBACK&apikey=' + key;
        console.log(url);
        request(url,function(error, response, body){
            if(error){
                callback(err);
            }

            if(!error && response.statusCode ==200){
                callback(null, body);
            }
        });
    }
};
```

it is calling an api with a json callback, when I am receiving the data it is in format:

```
JSON_CALLBACK({ json data here})
```

how can I get this endpoint to return just the json data, I have tried `JSON.parse()` but it causes errors in the server.

the angular service that calls this endpoint is like below:

```
 function getProfileData(battleTag){
            var defer = $q.defer();

            var tag = validTag(battleTag);
            if(!tag){
                defer.reject('Invalid Tag please use format 1[a-z]11[a-z0-9]#4[0-9]');  
                return defer.promise;             
            }

            $http.post('/api/profile', {
                    battleTag: battleTag
                })
               .success(function(data){
                    if(data.reason){
                        defer.resolve(data.reason);
                    }
                    defer.resolve(data);               
                })
                .error(function(err){
                    defer.reject(err);
                });

            return defer.promise;
        }
```

the call would work when using $http.jsonp in angular however I had to create the server to hide the secret key from the client

Comment: Do you get a valid JSON in your ```getProfileDataHttp```? What do you get in the ```body``` var?

Comment: JSON_CALLBACK({ json data here}) is what I get returned, but I cannot access this object because it is a function?

Comment: take a look here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9060270/node-http-request-for-restful-apis-that-return-jsonp I think this will help you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is a bit confusing. You are talking about JSONP, but you want to fetch the data directly.

The whole point of JSONP is to return the data encapsulated inside a function that you choose. You then simply have to execute it.

If you want the data in a direct way, don't use JSONP. Simply do a "normal" call.

After having a quick look at the [Battle.net API](https://dev.battle.net/io-docs), it seems that to get the data directly, you should simply omit the 'callback' parameter in the URL of your request.

Thus, your request URL would looks like that:

```
var url = 'https://eu.api.battle.net/d3/profile/'+ tag + '/?locale=en_GB&apikey=' + key;
```